# Chrome script to append URL when specific pattern match

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, web-scripting

I want to know if there is any scripting / plugin to append URL when I type specific text on chrome bar.
For example: If I type TEST-1245 or WEB-3912 to redirect me to https://example.com/TEST-1245 or https://example.com/WEB-3912

This helps when you have multiple projects on JIRA and you have only ticket id not entire URL